# How to pass data from an xlsx to another code row by row with python

Tags: python, excel, data-science

My requirement is that I have an xlsx workbook and I want to pass the values of specific columns in the below form to another code.
ex. (col1,col2,col3)
(col1,col2,col3)
(col1,col2,col3)
Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.